# body onload function not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html

I have a following code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   #visibilitycontent{
   visibility:hidden;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="visibilitychange()">
  <div id="header">
    This is header content.
  </div>
  <div id="visibilitycontent">
    This is main content.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    This is footer content.
  </div>
<script>
   function visibilitychange(){
   if($('#visibilitycontent').css('visibility','hidden')){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#visibilitycontent').css('visibility','initial');
        },2000);
     }
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The body **onload** function is working correctly in chrome and firefox, but it is not working on IE. On IE, the second div (**visibilitycontent**) is not changing its visibility from **hidden** to **initial**. How to make it working in IE.

Comment: why can't you use jQuery? `$(function(){//code here});` which is similar to `onload`

Comment: Can you please give an idea which method of jquery you are saying to use?

Comment: check the answer you received.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp check this link. If you are new to jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="visibilitychange()">
  <div id="header">
    This is header content.
  </div>
  <div id="visibilitycontent">
    This is main content.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    This is footer content.
  </div>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function visibilitychange(){
    $('#visibilitycontent').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('#visibilitycontent').show();
        },2000);
     }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change of style using jquery is not working in IE. Dont use style. use `hide()` and `show()` function. I checked this in IE, works good. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: This solution is not working correctly in  chrome and FF. In this solution. Firstly, when page is loading, then content is displaying for 1-2 seconds. Then content is hidden for 2 seconds and then content is displaying. Actually page is very heavy, loaded with lot of images. I have just given sample of                                                                                               <div id="visibilitycontent">
    This is main content.
  </div>                               My requireement is that this div should not be displayed until page is fully loaded.

Comment: <div id="visibilitycontent"> This is main content. </div>  Actually this is loaded with lot of images and content. So, it takes time to load. I want it should be displayed at any cost until page is loaded completely. With the solution provided above, the content displays for 1-2 seconds, then hide and then after 2 seconds , it displayed.

Comment: Thanks for idea. From the above idea, I have done as:                          <head><style>#visibilitycontent{display:none; }  </style>
</head>                      <body><script>
   function visibilitychange(){
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('#visibilitycontent').show();
        },2000);
     }
   </script></body>

Comment: @Ishpreet ok... if you have any other queries just comment here. Is that works now?

Answer (score 1):

If you using `jquery` then just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // On 2000ms (2s) after DOM Ready
    }, 2000);
});
```

Or

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
        // On 2000ms (2s) after DOM Ready
    }, 2000);
});
```

they both bind to DOM ready.

Comment: My problem is: I don't want to show content until page is loaded completely plus after 2-3 seconds after loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
if($('#visibilitycontent').css('visibility','hidden'))
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        $('#visibilitycontent').css('visibility','initial');
    },2000);
}
});
```

This will work. Install jQuery plugin and give the reference link.

Try to learn jQuery it will be useful and effective.

Comment: Same problem is arising. Your code also perfectly working in chrome and FF, but not in IE.

Comment: @Ishpreet which version of IE you are using?

Comment: yeah got your point.. you are right this is not working in IE. check my another answer... completely changed my old answer. which works good.